# Счётчик цифр за заданное время js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 4 разных числа, нужно за 1 период времени, например, 5 секунд, провести отсчёт от 0 до указанного в счётчике числа. Т.е. числа 50 и 5000 должны "отсчитаться" за одно время, но с разной скоростью. Получилось написать такой код, работает, но отсчитывает за разное время. Второй вопрос, как сократить код, используя массив?

```
        var count1 = $(".counter.active").find(".one .count").text(),
            count2 = $(".counter.active").find(".two .count").text(),
            count3 = $(".counter.active").find(".three .count").text(),
            count4 = $(".counter.active").find(".four .count").text(),
            countNum1 = Number(count1),
            countNum2 = Number(count2),
            countNum3 = Number(count3),
            countNum4 = Number(count4),
            activeCount = 0,
            time = 10000,
            intervalTime1 = time / countNum1,
            intervalTime2 = time / countNum2,
            intervalTime3 = time / countNum3,
            intervalTime4 = time / countNum4;
        function interval1() {
            activeCount ++;
            $(".counter.active").find(".one .count").text(activeCount);
            if(activeCount >= countNum1) {
                clearInterval(intervalID1);
            }
        }
        function interval2() {
            activeCount ++;
            $(".counter.active").find(".two .count").text(activeCount);
            if(activeCount >= countNum2) {
                clearInterval(intervalID2);
            }
        }
        function interval3() {
            activeCount ++;
            $(".counter.active").find(".three .count").text(activeCount);
            if(activeCount >= countNum3) {
                clearInterval(intervalID3);
            }
        }
        function interval4() {
            activeCount ++;
            $(".counter.active").find(".four .count").text(activeCount);
            if(activeCount >= countNum4) {
                clearInterval(intervalID4);
            }
        }
        var intervalID1 = setInterval(interval1, intervalTime1);
        var intervalID2 = setInterval(interval2, intervalTime2);
        var intervalID3 = setInterval(interval3, intervalTime3);
        var intervalID4 = setInterval(interval4, intervalTime4);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ

```
$('.counter.active .count').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
            $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
                    countNum: countTo
                },
                {
                    duration: 4000,
                    easing:'linear',
                    step: function() {
                        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $this.text(this.countNum);
                        //alert('finished');
                    }
                });
        });
```